# Xpath to select elements that has specific child

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

```
<item id=1>
  <name>item1</name>
  <price>30</price>
</item>
<item id=2>
  <name>item2</name>      
</item>
```

I need an xpath to select only items that DO NOT have price for .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your original question:

```
item[price]
```

will give you all `item` elements that have a `price` element child.  This includes an empty `<price/>` so if you want to avoid matching

```
<item>
  <name>item3</name>
  <price></price>
</item>
```

then you need one of the following

```
item[price/text()]
item[normalize-space(price)]
```

For the inverse, to select only `item` elements that do not have a `price`, you can use

```
item[not(price)]
```

Comment: please re-read the question again. I've edited it.