# Select children but exclude specific one

Tags: xpath

I have this XML structure:

```
<?version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
  <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" >
    <companyinfo>
      <addresses>
        <address type="mailing" >
          <city>NEW YORK</city>
        </address>
        <address type="business" >
          <city>NEW YORK</city>
        </address>
        <node1>node1</node1>
        <node2>node2</node2>
        <node3>nod3</node3>
      </addresses>
    </companyinfo>
  </feed>
```

I want to select all **children** of `<companyinfo>` but exclude `addresses` from the result. Meaning my selection becomes all the `<nodeX>`.

After reading around and looking at related threads [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862239/xpath-get-node-with-no-child-of-specific-type) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764383/xpath-to-select-elements-that-has-specific-child?noredirect=1&lq=1), I came up with the following:

`//companyinfo[not(addresses)]` # does not work

`//companyinfo/*[not(addresses)]` # does not work

Am I misunderstanding how `not(expr)` works?

Am I actually trying to select `companyinfo` **IF** `addresses` node is not present?

Comment: Did not work...

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is invalid, but if you fix it (and the typo), this expression, though convoluted,

```
//*[local-name()="companyinfo"]//*[local-name()="addresses"]//*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[local-name()="address"])]
```

should output

```
node1
node2
node3
```

Comment: It does work! It works as well like this: //*[local-name()="addresses"]//*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[local-name()="address"])]. Are you able to explain why it needs to be done like that?

Comment: @rock3t You don't really need with `companyinfo` just like you don't need to deal with `feed`; the critical node is `addresses` and its children. The reason you have to go through this `local-name()` process is the concept of namespaces. It's a long and sometimes painful subject and you need to learn about it. Start, for example, with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6397369/9448090.